# Remove a user from an access group in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, usergroups, access-rights

I need to remove a user from Administration group (settings/Access Rights).
I tried below code but nothing happened.

**Custom_module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <openerp>
    <data>
      <record model="res.users" id="base.user_root">
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(3,ref('base.group_system'))]"/>
      </record>
    </data>
  </openerp>
```

**/base/base_securit.xml**

```
<data noupdate="1">
      <record model="res.groups" id="group_system">
        <field name="name">Settings</field>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_erp_manager'))]"/>
        <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
    </record>
</data>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<record model="res.groups" id="base.group_system">
    <field name="users" eval="[(3,ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

Can you try the opposite? From the groups model remove the user from the group?

Comment: Thanks Philip.. it works.. But there is a problem. it works only in a fresh database not in my current one ?

Comment: Wierd, maybe the xml id is already flagged with `no update` ?

Comment: Are you saying the xml file has no noupdate flag or the ir.model.data record corresponding to your record has no noupdate flag on it. They should be the same. But its worth taking a look.

Comment: Updated my question. pls take a look.

Comment: What about the origin `res.users` record for admin? Has it `no update`, too?